# while + present continuous and present perfect

Tags: usage, present-perfect, present-continuous

Good evening,

Are correct the following?

- While I'm writing to you, I've packed my stuff.
- As I'm writing to you, I packed my stuff.

The meaning is that while writing I sometimes stopped to pack my stuff and finished packing.
Thank you very much

Comment: The grammar for the question should be "Are the following correct?".  What is your concern about these? Why do you doubt that they are correct?

Comment: There are lots of other tenses and aspects to use.  I might suggest "While I was writing to you, I packed my stuff".  Or to split the sentences, or to not mention "writing" at all.

Comment: "In between" or "In the intervals of writing to you, I've been packing my stuff."

Comment: [grammar: Are the following correct?] (Please fix your question. I don't edit this kind of thing so the OPs can learn for themselves the correct structure.)

Answer (score 0):

In both of your sentences, you mix present and past tenses - it doesn't make sense to have *writing* be in the present tense with *packed* in the past tense if the two events happened at the same time.

Instead, you could say:

- "I'm writing to you while I'm packing my stuff."
- "I'm packing my stuff while I'm writing to you."
- "I was writing to you while I packed my stuff."
- "I packed my stuff while I was writing to you."